# Посмотрите мое сочинение рассуждение, укажите ошибки и недочеты(я не обижусь), и сакжите что надо исправить

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Тема такая: надо взять любой афоризм и доказать его тремя аргументами.
Вот сочинение:
Я согласен с афоризмом Наполеона Бонапарта "В моем словаре нет слова невозможно" и понимаю его так: всегда надо идти к цели. Нужно пробовать и жизнь обязательно наградит вас за старания.
Во-первых, если вы будете употреблять слово «невозможно», то у вас никогда ничего не будет получаться. Надо уметь пересилить себя, свою боль. Примером послужит поступок Фродо Бэггинс из книги Дж. Толкиена «Властелин колец». Мальчику надо было уничтожить кольцо, а чтобы это сделать: преодолеть большой путь со многими сложностями и препятствиями. Он не обращал ни на что: его посадили в тюрьму – он выбрался, его единственный проводник хотел его убить – Фродо все равно шел, куда ему показывал провожатый. И только не сдаваясь, не говоря слово невозможно Фродо все же смог уничтожить кольцо.
Во-вторых, если вы будете употреблять слово невозможно, это может стоить жизни. Примером послужит реальный случай со времен Великой Отечественной Войны, описанный в книге Бориса Полевого «Повесть о настоящем человеке». Летчик Алексей Мересьев потерпел аварию на большом расстоянии от Родины. Его ноги не могли двигаться, и ему пришлось почти ползком добираться до своих. Он не сказал слова невозможно и выжил, несмотря на то что у него во время аварии почти не было еды. Когда Алексей добрался до своих, он опять же не сдался, а решил попробовать воевать в протезах. Превозмогая боль, он защищал Родину.
В-третьих, нельзя употреблять слово невозможно, даже если жизнь предоставила Вам какую-то проблему. В книге Элеонора Портера «Поллианна» хорошо описан такой случай. У девочки сироты, приехавшей к своей тетке, которая не любила ее оказалась травма с ногами. Врач сказал Поллианне, что она больше не сможет ходить. Но девочка не сломилась, не перестала радоваться окружающему миру. Она во всем искала счастье. Не обращая внимания на свою проблему, она подбадривала и утешала остальных. Спустя некоторое время врачи поняли, что ошиблись и вылечили ноги Поллианне.
Вот почему, я полностью согласен с афоризмом Наполеона Бонапарта «В моем словаре нет слова невозможно».

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я предложу вам свое редактирование текста.  Основные недочеты –  повторы, лишние слова, сложное построение фраз. Это публицистический стиль, где нужно убедить собеседника, воздействовать на него эмоционально. Краткость и выразительность – вот что здесь важно.

***В моем словаре нет слов «невозможно», «не умею», «не могу».*** (Наполеон Бонапарт)

Я согласен с афоризмом Наполеона Бонапарта "В моем словаре нет слова *невозможно*" и понимаю его так: всегда надо идти к своей цели, если она важна для вас. Нужно пробовать, и жизнь обязательно наградит за старания.

Если сказать  – «это невозможно!», то ничего и не получится. Надо уметь пересилить себя, свои сомнения и свою боль. Примером может служить поступок Фродо Бэггинс из книги Дж. Толкиена «Властелин колец». Мальчику надо было уничтожить кольцо, а чтобы это сделать – преодолеть большой путь со многими сложностями и препятствиями. Он не обращал внимания ни на что: его посадили в тюрьму – он выбрался, его единственный проводник хотел его убить – Фродо все равно шел, куда ему показывал провожатый. И только не сдаваясь, забыв про «невозможность»,  он все же смог добиться цели.

Слово «невозможно»  иногда может  стоить жизни. Примером служит реальный случай во времена Великой Отечественной Войны, описанный в книге Бориса Полевого «Повесть о настоящем человеке». Летчик Алексей Мересьев потерпел аварию на  занятой территории, причем на большом расстоянии от  фронта. Его ноги не могли двигаться, и ему пришлось ползком добираться до своих. Он забыл о «невозможном»  и выжил, хотя  каждое движение причиняло страдание и у него почти не было еды. Он лишился ног, но опять же не сдался, а решил воевать в протезах. Превозмогая боль, он защищал Родину.

Нельзя употреблять слово «невозможно», даже если жизнь поставила перед вами  какую-то проблему. В книге Элеонора Портера «Поллианна» хорошо описан такой случай. У девочки-сироты, приехавшей к своей тетке, которая не любила ее,  были травмированы ноги. Врач сказал Поллианне, что она больше не сможет ходить. Но девочка не сломилась, не перестала радоваться окружающему миру. Она во всем искала счастье. Не обращая внимания на свою боль, она подбадривала и утешала остальных. Спустя некоторое время врачи поняли, что ошиблись,  и вылечили ноги Поллианне.

Вот почему я хотел бы, чтобы  моем словаре, как и у Наполеона Бонапарта,  не  было слова «невозможно».

Comment: Спасибки огромное!))

Comment: Пожалуйста! :))  Надеюсь увидеть вас постоянным участником форума.

Comment: Так скорее всего оно и будет) Если я конечно не уйду на английский форум, где учат русский))

Comment: Ну да, где еще выучить русский язык, как не на английском форуме:)

Comment: Кстати, мой ответ отминусовали, а "записочку" не приложили. Может, надо вводные слова  (во-первых, во-вторых) вернуть на место или еще что не понравилось. Так что проверьте соответствие текста школьному формату.

Comment: Да нет, все у Вас хорошо!